# Using SQL and PHP to return ranked results from MySQL

Tags: php, sql, drupal

I'm trying to come up with the correct syntax for a SQL query using PHP (in a drupal site) but I need some guidance.

Here is my idea (in Drupal module - already designed). User makes selections from multi-page form (3 pages, radio buttons on each page, only 1 selection allowed per page). I want these to be submitted to the database and have the MySQL database return recommendations for the user depending on what their selections were, ranked in order of how many of their selections match those criteria in the resources in the database. So for example a user might select *novice* for exp level and *founder* for role and *entrepreneuralship* (made up word) as their topics of interest (the 3 questions in the form).

If a Resource in the database had all 3 of these set for those fields (as part of a field list), we'd want it returned near the top of the results (if more than 1 had all 3 we'd want them ordered alphabetically - ascending), followed by any resources that had at least 2 of these matching list terms (with corresponding alphabetic ranking between those second tier resources), followed by items that matched only ONE of the checked items. Items that return 0 matches shouldn't be displayed at all.

What I've done is put together a Drupal and PHP code-based concept I'm hoping for feedback on this. The code below is the function that's called after the user submits the form and are redirected to the `/recommendations` page. What I'd like feedback on primarily is setting the PHP variables at the top, the SQL in my `$result` var which is my best guess how this would work, and then a bunch of `if/while` statements to do the ordering and returning of data to the screen.

Any help in making this more functional code would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
function pathfindertool_recommendations_page() {
$output = '';

$level = $_SESSION['level'];
$level = mysql_real_escape_string($level);
$role = $_SESSION['role'];
$role = $level = mysql_real_escape_string($role);
$topic = $_SESSION['topic'];
$topic = mysql_real_escape_string($topic);

$result = db_query("SELECT n.nid, n.title, n.type, fdb.body_value, fdfe.field_experience_level_value, fdfi.field_icon, fdfl.field_link_url, fdfr.field_role_value, fdft.field_topics_value FROM {node} as n INNER JOIN {field_data_body} as fdb INNER JOIN {field_data_field_experience} as fdfe INNER JOIN {field_data_field_icon} as fdfi INNER JOIN {field_data_field_link} as fdfl INNER JOIN {field_data_field_role} as fdfr INNER JOIN {field_data_field_topics} as fdft on n.nid = fdb.entity_id on n.nid = fdfe on n.nid = fdfi on n.nid= fdfl on n.nid = fdfr on n.nid = fdft WHERE n.type = :type", array(':type' => 'resource',) "AND fdfe.field_experience_level_value = :level", array(':level' => '$level',) "AND fdfr.field_role_value = :role", array(':role' => '$role',) AND fdft.field_topics_value = :topic", array(':topic' => '$topic',) ORDER BY ASC);

if($result) {
    while ($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
    // If all three match
        while (($row['field_data_experience_level'] = $level) && ($row['field_data_field_role'] = '$role') && ($row['field_data_field_topics'] = $topic)) {
            $title = row['title'];
            $link = row['field_data_field_link'];
            $body = row['body_value'];
            $icon = row['field_icon'];
            $output .= '<p> . $title . <br> . $icon . <br> . $body . <br> . $link';
            return $output;
        }       
        // If at least two match
        while (($row['field_data_experience_level'] = $level) && ($row['field_data_field_role'] = '$role') OR ($row['field_data_field_topics'] = $topic)) {
            $title = row['title'];
            $link = row['field_data_field_link'];
            $body = row['body_value'];
            $icon = row['field_icon'];
            $output .= '<p> . $title . <br> . $icon . <br> . $body . <br> . $link';
            return $output;
        }
        while (($row['field_data_experience_level'] = $level) OR ($row['field_data_field_role'] = '$role') && ($row['field_data_field_topics'] = $topic)) {
            $title = row['title'];
            $link = row['field_data_field_link'];
            $body = row['body_value'];
            $icon = row['field_icon'];
            $output .= '<p> . $title . <br> . $icon . <br> . $body . <br> . $link';
            return $output;
        }
        // Just if only one matches
        while (($row['field_data_experience_level'] = $level) OR ($row['field_data_field_role'] = '$role') OR ($row['field_data_field_topics'] = $topic)) {
            $title = row['title'];
            $link = row['field_data_field_link'];
            $body = row['body_value'];
            $icon = row['field_icon'];
            $output .= '<p> . $title . <br> . $icon . <br> . $body . <br> . $link';
            return $output;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my SQL:

```
$result = db_query("
SELECT n.nid,
       n.title,
       n.type,
       fdb.body_value,
       fdfe.field_experience_level_value,
       fdfi.field_icon,
       fdfl.field_link_url,
       fdfr.field_role_value,
       fdft.field_topics_value
FROM {node} AS n
INNER JOIN {field_data_body} AS fdb
INNER JOIN {field_data_field_experience} AS fdfe
INNER JOIN {field_data_field_icon} AS fdfi
INNER JOIN {field_data_field_link} AS fdfl
INNER JOIN {field_data_field_role} AS fdfr
INNER JOIN {field_data_field_topics} AS fdft ON n.nid = fdb.entity_id ON n.nid = fdfe ON n.nid = fdfi ON n.nid= fdfl ON n.nid = fdfr ON n.nid = fdft
WHERE n.type = :type
",
array(':type' => 'resource',) "AND fdfe.field_experience_level_value = :level", array(':level' => '$level',) "AND fdfr.field_role_value = :role", array(':role' => '$role',) AND fdft.field_topics_value = :topic", array(':topic' => '$topic',) ORDER BY ASC);
```

Comment: It sounds like you've done a fair bit of thinking about how it will work, but so little of the SQL and PHP is done that, if someone were to help, they'd be doing the whole lot. As such I think that, as interesting as the question is, it seems rather too broad for Stack Overflow, and could do with at least the start of an implementation being edited in. Readers would need a database schema too. I wonder if you need a Drupal freelancer, to help you with getting started?

Comment: Yea, you're probably right. I don't have the aid of anyone else however so I'll just start working on the SQL/PHP myself. Any idea where I might go to learn about the SQL and/or PHP I'd need to develop this? Any links at all would be helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, you could improve the question. Edit in the structure of the database table(s) that will be involved, and some sample data - ideally creating a SQL Fiddle and adding a link. I'd try solving it in SQL first but several separate SQL calls and and some PHP may be necessary.

Comment: Since you have a maximum of three matches, it may be possible just to `SELECT` from one table and `LEFT JOIN` to three other tables/sub-selects, and then use PHP to count the matches, or to do `IF` statements in SQL that will reflect whether you have 1, 2 or 3 matches. At this stage there is no structure/data for people to get their heads around, but if you make the change I mention then someone may be able to help further.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will do some research and post again!

Comment: @halfer Hi again - I finally added some code for you to take a look at when you have some time. I edited my original post; please take a look. Thank you!

Comment: I've done some formatting of the unformatted SQL - it wasn't very readable as it was. You may wish to reformat further, as I think some of your string clauses in the array are missing quotes or commas (in both blocks of code). As for the problem, can you narrow it down? At the moment it seems like you have everything working, but just want a code review. If so, this is not the best site - _Code Review_ is best for that. If you have something that doesn't work, can you make that clear?